# Custom object Asynchronous calls to create a record for multiple user's in same point of time?

Tags: apex

I have a object called Insurance__c in that i have a fields called

```
1.insurancName__c
2.StartDate__c
3.EndDate__c
4.Duration__c
```

Now my question is to you guys if four users are crate a record on `Insurance__c` object then,i got Created `RecordId(AutoNumber)` same to all the four users who are creating record at same point of time(Same seconds).

so, i want different `RecordId(AutoNumber)` for different use.

Please help me out to achieve this task.

Thanks & regards,

J Ramprasad.

Comment: Did you find the `RecordId(AutoNumber)` is duplicate for records created at same time? It shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_types.htm&language=en_US), the Auto Number type field:

> Automatically assigns a **unique** number to each record. (Emphasis added)

You will get a different auto-number for each record, even if users hit save at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Any record in salesforce is defined with a unique record id. Based on the time the record saved to the db when it satisfies all the criteria a unique record id or auto number is generated.

RecordId:

For all entity types, every record has an ID field that uniquely identifies that record. The value for the ID field is created automatically upon insert, and it cannot change over the lifetime of that record, even if the record is deleted and then undeleted. Each ID value is guaranteed to be globally unique. The ID of a record is the best way to uniquely identify that record.

AutoNumber:

The unique identifiers for solutions, cases, and contracts are standard auto-number fields. Each record is assigned a unique number with a specified format upon creation. You can modify the format and numbering for these auto-number fields.